# Encapsulating nested component port communication in Elm?

Tags: javascript, elm

I have a reusable Elm component that is intended to be reused in multiple places (in the style of the [guide tutorial](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/modularity/counter_pair.html). I have a Javascript function that I would like to communicate with via ports, but creating a port subscription causes every "instance" of my component to receive every message that I send back from Javascript.

Ideally, parent components should not need to do any filtering beyond the usual `Cmd.map ChildMsg`. The simplest solution I can come up with is to add an ID to each child model and filter in the child's own update function, but this is a bit unfortunate, and requires me to fabricate an ID if one doesn't already exist.

As an example of my ideal result, the `Http` modules allows you to return a task and receive the result back, addressed only to the specific instance that requested it. I've managed to emulate this behavior with a simplistic `Native` module: https://github.com/tgecho/elm-custom-task-example

```
function getNumber(number) {
    return _elm_lang$core$Native_Scheduler.nativeBinding(function(callback) {
            return callback(_elm_lang$core$Native_Scheduler.succeed(number));
    });
}
```

Then my component can call this function by returning a task `Task.perform NaN Increment (Number.getNumber 1)` and will receive the result back as an Increment message.

What am I missing? Is there a way to encapsulate port communication **without writing Native** code or adding IDs to everything?

Comment: If the children are all the same, use an Array rather than a List and you get indexing for free